# Anotating properties of an object literal

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in `TypeScript` to anotate the properties of an object literal to a type ?

Consider the following example:

```
interface ILiteralType
{
    // I don't know what is going to be part of this object
    // but I know it should be of type string.
    *: string;
}

class MyClass
{
    properties: ILiteralType;
}

var m = new MyClass();
m.properties = {
    name: "A name",           // ok
    age: 10,                  // error: Should be a string
    anotherProp: "some value" // ok too
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
interface ILiteralType
{
    [property: string]: string;
}
```

That will require all of the property values to be strings.